# jQuery hover script acts sporadic

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a basic jquery script that, when an image is hovered pushes the image up. Hover it sometimes doesnt work as expected. I wonder if there's anything else i can add in my script to make it function as expected ALL the time and not just intermittently.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("#image-list a").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "-10px" }, "fast");
            $(this).parent().find("span").stop().animate({ marginTop: "18px", opacity: 0.25 }, "fast");
        },function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, "fast");
            $(this).parent().find("span").stop().animate({ marginTop: "1px", opacity: 1 }, "fast");
        });     


    // create custom animation algorithm for jQuery called "bouncy"
    $.easing.bouncy = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s = 1.70158;
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
    }

    // create custom tooltip effect for jQuery Tooltip
    $.tools.tooltip.addEffect(
        "bouncy",

    // opening animation
    function(done) {
        this.getTip().animate({top: '+=10'}, 300, 'bouncy', done).show();
    },

    // closing animation
    function(done) {
        this.getTip().animate({top: '-=10'}, 50, 'bouncy', function()  {
        $(this).hide();
        done.call();
        });
    }
    );                                          

    $("a.cat-pics img[title]").tooltip({effect: 'bouncy'});

 });
```

HTML

```
    <ul id="image-list">
<li class=""><a class="cat-pics" href="http://www.greatshield.com/dev/products/devices/apple/"><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/iphone-5.jpg" title="iPhone 5"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Link
http://www.greatshield.com/dev/products/device-type/smartphones/

Comment: Just wondering, if all you're doing is changing the margin on hover, can you not do this with CSS?

Comment: &Matthew Riches - I could use CSS but wouldnt it not work in older browsers?

Comment: A hover on an anchor just changing the margin should work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply the tooltip on `img`, but the hover on `a`

Instead of hovering on `a` try hovering on `img`

```
$("#image-list img").hover(function() {
```

Or at least make then both the same one way or the other.  I think the `img` margins are messing you up.